# Restarting WinRM Service

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I need to restart the Windows Remote Management Service on Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller during office hours, what are the potential risks of doing this and what it can impact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the service description:

> Windows Remote Management (WinRM) service implements the WS-Management
> protocol for remote management. WS-Management is a standard web
> services protocol used for remote software and hardware management.
> The WinRM service listens on the network for WS-Management requests
> and processes them. The WinRM Service needs to be configured with a
> listener using winrm.cmd command line tool or through Group Policy in
> order for it to listen over the network. The WinRM service provides
> access to WMI data and enables event collection. Event collection and
> subscription to events require that the service is running. WinRM
> messages use HTTP and HTTPS as transports. The WinRM service does not
> depend on IIS but is preconfigured to share a port with IIS on the
> same machine.  The WinRM service reserves the /wsman URL prefix. To
> prevent conflicts with IIS, administrators should ensure that any
> websites hosted on IIS do not use the /wsman URL prefix.

You should be fine to restart the service. It will have no effect on domain clients.